# Login using Flex and PHP but how to handle session

Tags: php, apache-flex, authentication

I have a Flex login page that uses HTTPService to communicate with server side php script. Once user's credential is verified, a session will be created and the login page will redirect to the main Flex page with that session info.

I'm not sure how to implement the session logic. Can someone shed some light on this? Some sample codes will be very helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

This looks promising: http://corlan.org/2008/07/22/flex-air-php-and-user-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the browser's session cookies and some of PHP's built-in support for that you can also use ExternalInterface to reach out to the browser and pass the cookie information back and forth with some PHP and your Flash embed code.

The comments in this post have some more information on the upsides/downsides to that approach - http://www.rooftopsolutions.nl/article/117

=Ryan
ryan@adobe.com